# Magento 2 In which database table is the attribute Position stored?

Tags: database, attributes, magento-2.2.5, position

I need to write my own MySQL query, where I need to use the attribute Position in the query. But I can not see which table attributes Position stored in. In my `*eav_attribute*` table, the attribute Position has attribute_id 56. I have tried to look at the table *`catalog_product_entity_int`*, but no attribute_id equals 56. I wonder which table else could contain the product Position value?

And the position attribute I'm talking about is as in this screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the positions of category products in table **catalog_category_product**

You can also see more fields like category_id and product_id as well which means which product is assign with which category with position.

Comment: Thanks. I found it now. I can first accept your answer after 10 minutes. I wonder if theres any good ways to search for a Magento attribute in database? or you just need to know where it is located?

Comment: You need to know the database architecture and also the eav structure of magento then only you can find the tables very easily.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using ElasticSearch, the right table to look into is **smile_virtualcategory_catalog_category_product_position**. This table stores the manually arranged products.

After that, the actual sort order of the rest of the products (the automatically sorted ones from backend) is their **entity_id** field DESC